# Moving data from Word to Access seamlessly

Tags: excel, ms-access, formatting, ms-word, newline

I am trying to migrate structured documents (i.e. documents that are mostly some metadata and one big table) to a database. When I try to move tabular data from Word to Excel, my main point of pain is handling CRLFs within a cell in Word. Any solution for this?
Now, since I will be transferring from Word to Access:

1. What will be the default behaviour when I attempt to populate a field with a string that contains a CRLF?
2. What is the cheapest way to get Access to respect "rich text"? (mostly boldface and overstrike)

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

1. It should just enter the two characters as any other two characters.
2. HTML is a pretty good solution.

For a more detailed answer, we should probably know *how* you are doing this "migration".